# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory trying to install Oracle SOA Suite 12.2.1.4.0

Tags: java, weblogic, soa, jdeveloper

I'm trying to install Oracle SOA Suite 12.2.1.4.0 on my work laptop.
I'm using a script that sets enviroment variables, like java path, so I'm using a particular version (jdk1.8.0_211)

The script is this:

```
set DEVROOT=C:\WORKINGDIR
set M2_HOME=%DEVROOT%\Apps\apache-maven-3.2.5
set JAVA_HOME=%DEVROOT%\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

java -verbose -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar`
```

Is there something I can do about?

This is the log:

```
[Opened C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
...
...
[Loaded com.oracle.xmlns.oui.options.GroupType from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.xmlns.oui.options.OptionType from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.xmlns.oui.options.OperationType from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.xmlns.oui.options.ReferenceType from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.xmlns.oui.options.OperationOptionType from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.xmlns.oui.options.OptionsInfoType from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.xmlns.oui.options.OptionsStructureType from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.xmlns.oui.options.OptionsType from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded javax.xml.bind.GetPropertyAction from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.logging.LogRecord from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputHandlerException: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getOptionsInfoDao(OptionsParser.java:550)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.parseOptionsDao(OptionsParser.java:219)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.<init>(OptionsParser.java:142)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getInstance(OptionsParser.java:129)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.OUIOptions.<init>(OUIOptions.java:59)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputsImpl.<init>(InputsImpl.java:53)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputsImpl.getInstance(InputsImpl.java:60)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.helpers.InputHandler.getInputs(InputHandler.java:41)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.processCommandLineArgs(Launcher.java:3261)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:4035)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:3969)
Caused by: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
        at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.getUnmarshaller(JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.java:359)
        at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.create(JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.java:154)
        at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.parse(DaoHelper.java:224)
        at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getRootWrapper(DaoHelper.java:693)
        at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getOptionsInfoDao(OptionsParser.java:546)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:226)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:390)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
        at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.getUnmarshaller(JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl.java:340)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:579)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:224)
        ... 18 more
[Loaded com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.CommandLineParser from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.utils.Util from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FileFilter from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.LinkedHashSet from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.NLS from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.cie.common.util.ResourceBundleManager from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded com.oracle.cie.common.util.ResourceBundleManager$ResourceNamespace from INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.ResourceBundleEnumeration from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputHandlerException: com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.InputHandlerException: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
[Loaded java.text.MessageFormat from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Formatter$FormatString from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Formatter$FixedString from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]

Press Enter to exit
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$IdentityHashMapIterator from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeyIterator from C:\WORKINGDIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
```

I've used a lot of jdk version (1.7 and 1.8), but all of that got me on this error.
I've cleand every java reference on my pc and reinstalled lots of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the "+" character in your installation path : INSTALLER_PATH/Software/jdev+soa12/fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar
Move and run the jar file from another path where there is no special chararcters.

Comment: It was that! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The error may be cause due to your existing eclipse or some other editor settings overriding!

Run your script, You can verify the path with dir command in the CMD window, where it is trying to look for %JAVA_HOME%\jre is existing or not

```
dir %JAVA_HOME%\jre
```

If above command returns the content of the jre folder it is good. Otherwise,
alternatively try by setting up the CLASSPATH to null.
`SET CLASSPATH=""`

Try 2:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar
```

Did you tried with the latest virion of JDK?
Please respond back with what happen when you used above suggestions.

Comment: thanks for the help, but no change to the output, sorry

Comment: gosphalt Could you please share the command output for `dir %JAVA_HOME%\jre`

Comment: `Directory of C:\WORK_DIR\Apps\jdk1.8.0_211\jre

03/05/2019  14:06    <DIR>          .
03/05/2019  14:06    <DIR>          ..
03/05/2019  14:06    <DIR>          bin
03/05/2019  14:06             3.244 COPYRIGHT
03/05/2019  14:07    <DIR>          lib
03/05/2019  14:06                44 LICENSE
03/05/2019  14:06                46 README.txt
03/05/2019  14:06           112.748 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
03/05/2019  14:06           149.725 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
03/05/2019  14:06               955 Welcome.html`

Comment: Could you only try with the following command :  Open the CMD in freshly then `java  -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar`